# Get source link of the first image in a Bing search using curl

Tags: web-scraping, curl

I want to get the source link of the first image that appears in the Bing image search results for a specified search term.

I am currently using this command, but get no output:

```
curl -s "https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover" | grep -o '<a class="thumb" target="_blank" href="[^"]*'
```

Running only `curl -s "https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover"` displays HTML code of the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should generally avoid parsing HTML with regex, which bobnice explains better than I can, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1067003

for example [PHP](https://linux.die.net/man/1/php) can parse HTML with its [DOMDocument API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
curl -s 'https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover' | php -r '$html = stream_get_contents(STDIN);$domd=new DOMDocument();@$domd->loadHTML($html);$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);var_dump($xp->query("//a[@data-hookid='\''pgdom'\'']")->item(0)->getAttribute("href"));'
```

prints

> string(34) "https://pxhere.com/en/photo/609263"

the source of the first image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @hanshenrik. Thanks to your command I get the link of the page where the picture is, but how to get the link to that picture for example, website.com/images/cat.jpeg?

Comment: @Robin maybe try the XPath ```//a[contains(@class,'iusc')]//img```

Comment: I get empty string with that command unfortunately.

`curl -s 'https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=cat&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover' | php -r '$html = stream_get_contents(STDIN);$domd=new DOMDocument();@$domd->loadHTML($html);$xp = new DOMXPath($domd);var_dump($xp->query("//a[contains(@class,'iusc')]//img")->item(0)->getAttribute("href"));'`

Comment: @Robin `<a` elements use `href` and `<img` elements use `src`, so first you ned to change `getAttribute("href")` to `getAttribute("src");` , second you need to apply [shell quoting rules](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html) to your XPath when adding your XPath to the shell command, so it would be ```"//a[contains(@class,'\''iusc'\'')]//img"``` - fix both of those and try again :) screenshot (because a fixed command is too long to add as a comment): https://i.imgur.com/s5fUAfs.png

Comment: I'm coming back to you because the first image displayed on bing is now ai-generated. How can I modify the command to obtain the link for the second image? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Robin dunno, if you're lucky, you just have to replace `->item(0)` with `->item(1)` in the code. If that doesn't work, send $10 to paypal `divinity76@gmail.com`  and I will investigate.

Comment: I am lucky. I saved your paypal anyway. Have a great one.